# Image data usage

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am building a chat mobile application. I have bunch of people in directory and each person has their profile image.

When I go to the page, it downloads profile images using a lot of data.

Here is my question:
even if the images are cached, it still uses a lot of data to download profile images every time access to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much data you use is going to depend on the image provider - but React doesn't handle image caching very well imo especially in lists so you could see multiple downloads of the same image throughout the use of the app.

Perhaps try an image caching component like [react-native-cached-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cached-image). Haven't personally used this.

There is another called [Progressive Image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-progressive-image) that doesn't cache but smoothes the process of donwloading an image.

It uses the [blur up technique](https://css-tricks.com/the-blur-up-technique-for-loading-background-images/) to smoothly render images.
It downloads a small version of the file, blurs it whilst downloading the larger image and then fades from small to large image. It works very well and provides a smoother render.

Hope that helps.